# How to create progress bar based on an image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Is there a way I can create a progress bar based on an image like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouBPj.png)?

The user is supposed to build a building and I wanted to show the progress of the building process.
**Example:** if the progress is 50%, the top 50% of the building should be cut off.

I tried to put an image inside a UIImageView with alpha 0.3 to show what the eventual building would look like. Like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPaxl.png).

And I tried to put the same image inside a UIImageView with alpha: 1.0, Clip To Bounds selected and contentmode: Aspect fill so I could programmatically change the height of the UIImageView according to the progress. But as you see in the image the building moves a bit if you change the height of the UIImageView. Like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrLkk.png).

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/Marxon13/M13ProgressSuite

Comment: put a view over imageview and increase height of view according to progress.

Comment: @Bhaumik works like a charm, thanks!